# How to map specific port inside docker container when using traefik?

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, traefik

Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  website:
    build: ./website
    expose: [3000]
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost"
  blog:
    build: ./blog
    expose: [4000]
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefix:/blog"
  docs:
    build: ./docs
    expose: [3000]
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:localhost;PathPrefix:/docs"
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

What I want is access three different node.js websites via different routes. But these three node.js websites actually expose different ports. Now my treafik is running. I can config via `localhost:8080` But `localhost` `localhost/blog` and `localhost/docs` are all `404 page not found`

**P.S**: I'm not sure whether port is the issue I should investigate, because changing one node.js service to `port 80` doesn't solve the puzzle. And I saw on traefik dashboard the rule is **Host(`blog-dev`)**

Comment: Are you using traefix 2?.

Comment: @Keith Yes. Currently latest. So it's v2.1

Comment: Ok, see my answer.

Comment: In my case, I needed to not use "ports" in docker-compose.yml because that exposes the containers but without "ports" it wouldn't work. The solution was to use "expose" instead.

Answer (score 7):

`PathPrefix:/blog`

When you have this as a routing rule, traefix won't automatically remove the prefix when sending to the container.

So unless you have a route `/blog` inside your container you will get a 404.

So what you normally do is also add a middleware to strip this ->
https://docs.traefik.io/middlewares/stripprefix/

Also you appear not to be setting your rules based on your service.

So as an example for your first service `blog`,

try->

```
labels:
    - "traefik.http.routers.blog.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/blog`)"
    - "traefik.http.routers.blog.middlewares=strip-blog"
    - "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-blog.stripprefix.prefixes=/blog"
```

And then do the same for your other routes, don't forget to replace `routers.blog` with `routers.docs` etc..

Comment: Thanks. So this is not about the port using inside those containers? I have one without any prefix but it's still 404.

Comment: @Desmond  Yes because `traefik.frontend.rule` is incorrect.. Should be -> `traefik.http.routers.website.rule=`  Can you see how `website` here maps with your service name?.

Comment: @Desmond   Also just spotted how your defining your rule, just updated to how I think it should look..  eg. `Host('localhost') && PathPrefix('/blog')`, (note: those are back ticks, just can't do them in comments) and not `Host:localhost;PathPrefix:/blog`

Comment: @Keith If my application has static content(js,bootstrap etc) that is served on basis of folder name, the solution won't work as there would be no matching route for these.
When these files would be accessed Traefik will again search for PathPrefix Blog.

Comment: @Keith refer to the question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186640/cant-resolve-url-in-traefik-getting-error-404

Answer (score 7):

```
labels: 
- traefik.http.services.<YOUR-SERVICE-NAME>.loadbalancer.server.port=9763
```

EG:

```
services:
  wso:
    image: "my-custom-wso-image"
    volumes:
      - .....
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wso.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wso.rule=Host(`my.nice.url`)"
      - "traefik.http.services.wso.loadbalancer.server.port=9763" #<-----
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me in v3.6.
By the way what is the job of loadbalancer by the way ?

Comment: @Priyal Load-Balancers are used to to efficiently distributing incoming network traffic across multiple backend services. You can configure multiple URL's in your loadbalancer and traefik will automaticaly distribute the traffic.
Example: https://github.com/swissbuechi/boilerplates/blob/main/docker-compose/traefik/config/service-example.yml
provider: `file`:

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Keith I found the solution

```
version: '3'
services:
  website:
    build: ./website
    expose: [3000]
    networks: # It's essential to specify the same network in every service
      - webgateway
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.website.rule=Host(`localhost`)" # Use the right format
      - "traefik.port=3000" # Let traefik find the right port
  blog:
    build: ./blog
    expose: [4000]
    networks:
      - webgateway
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.blog.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/blog`)" # blog has a root as `/blog` so no need to strip otherwise too many redirects
      - "traefik.port=4000"
  docs:
    build: ./docs
    expose: [3000]
    networks:
      - webgateway
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.docs.rule=Host(`localhost`) && PathPrefix(`/docs`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.docs.middlewares=strip-docs" # Necessary as Keith mentioned
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.strip-docs.stripprefix.prefixes=/docs"
      - "traefik.port=3000"
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```