# Can't resolve URL in Traefik Getting Error 404

Tags: docker, containers, reverse-proxy, traefik

The problem I am facing is somewhat known to me but still, I wanted to understand the problem in my implementation.

I have a Traefik container and a service container. The service container has certain routes that serves the pages. In order to pass the request from Traefik to the service/application container,I have attached a label to my container. The label has a path as the one in my application so that Traefik can redirect the request to backend service and finally my service can serve the request.

**Main Problem:** All works fine and dandy till now but the problem is that my application/service serves some static pages that are on another route not recognizable by Traefik. This will generate an Error 404. I am not able to find a way out of this problem.

**Eg:** I have a Service A that serves the request on http://localhost/blog and all the further requests go through **localhost/blog/*** . For this I would simply add the label with **PathPrefix(`/blog`)** It makes everything work but there is no JS and CSS files loaded. The reason for the same is that my css and js files are loaded from the http://localhost/js and http://localhost/css route. Of course this route is not recognized by Traefik.

**Docker-Compose.yml**

```
servicea:
        container_name: servicea-ge
        image: 'servicea'
        restart: always
        labels:
            - traefik.http.routers.servicea.rule=PathPrefix(`/blog`)
        networks:
            - internal-network
        logging:
            driver: json-file
            options: {max-size: 20m, max-file: '5'}
        environment:
            TZ: '${Time_Zone}'
networks:
    internal-network:
        driver: bridge
        name: test
```

I have tried a solution in which **I have added a middleware to strip /blog** but this will also cause further problems. Now the home page gets loaded successfully but the further routes like **/blog/addblog** start to fail as blog will be removed (reason strip middleware).
Eg:

```
- traefik.http.routers.servicea.middlewares=strip-blog
- traefik.http.middlewares.strip-blog.stripprefix.prefixes=/blog
```

Could anyone propose a solution to the above-described problem?